# Regex to get match on entire string

Tags: regex, sed

How to match a a word before a specific charachter using sed in bash?

In my scenario I would need to match the metrics names in the entire string which occurs only before `{`.

The below is the string I am working on.

```
sum(rate(nginx_ingress_controller_request_duration_seconds_sum{namespace=\"$namespace\",ingress=~\"$ingress\"}[3m]))/sum(rate(nginx_ingress_controller_request_duration_seconds_count{namespace=\"$namespace\",ingress=~\"$ingress\"}[3m]))
```

What I would need the output is the below.

`nginx_ingress_controller_request_duration_seconds_sum`

`nginx_ingress_controller_request_duration_seconds_count`

I am not a Regex expert and I would be very thankful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `GNU grep`:

```sh
grep -oP '\(\K[^({]+(?={)'
```

This will print the results in separate lines. `\(\K` will check for presence of `(` character and reset the start of matching portion (since `(` isn't needed in the output). `[^({]+` will match except `(` and `{` characters. `(?={)` makes sure that the matched portion is followed by `{` character (but not part of the output).

If you know that the required portion can have only word characters, you can also use:

```sh
grep -oP '\w+(?={)'
```

Answer (score 0):

This will look for two occurrences on the line onto a separate line in new_file
(with GNU sed):

```
sed 's/.*(\(.*\){.*(\(.*\){.*/\1\n\2/' your_file > new_file
```

Contents of new_file:

```
nginx_ingress_controller_request_duration_seconds_sum
nginx_ingress_controller_request_duration_seconds_count
```

The ways it's working is as follows:

- `/.*(`: Match everything after a `{` up to a `(`
- `\(.*\)`: I remember the stuff in between `\(` and `\)` (these are called
  capture group)
- `{.*(`: Match everything after a `{` up to a `(`
- `\(.*\)`: I remember a second group of stuff using a second capture group
- `{.*`: Match the rest of the stuff in the line
- `/\1\n\2/`: Put the two patterns we remembered back into a file a newline
  `\n` between.

#### Edit

Another approach that would would work for multiple occurrences would be to
create newlines and a unique patter at the points before and after the part of the string that
you're interested in, and then grep away those lines:

```
sed 's/(/BADLINES\n/g; s/{/\nBADLINES/g' your_file | grep -v BADLINES
```

The first part (`sed 's/(/BADLINES\n/g; s/{/\nBADLINES/g' your_file`) produces:

```
sumBADLINES
rateBADLINES
nginx_ingress_controller_request_duration_seconds_sum
BADLINESnamespace=\"$namespace\",ingress=~\"$ingress\"}[3m]))/sumBADLINES
rateBADLINES
nginx_ingress_controller_request_duration_seconds_count
BADLINESnamespace=\"$namespace\",ingress=~\"$ingress\"}[3m]))
```

and the `| grep -v BADLINES` produces:

```
nginx_ingress_controller_request_duration_seconds_sum
nginx_ingress_controller_request_duration_seconds_count
```

Comment: Thanks @mattb, How about if there are multiple occurrences?

Comment: @UvaisIbrahim: `sed 's/(/\n/g; s/{/\n/g' your_file | grep nginx` (this might be brittle)

Comment: Hi @mattb, can I get a generic one regex for a string like this?
sdvajsd(asdabda(output{asdbasdada}))/zcjabcc(knbcnbc(output1{asbdvabsd}))
and the output should be,
output
output1

Comment: @UvaisIbrahim I made an edit that should work for such a string

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '/^(\w+)\{/{s//\1\n/;P;D};s/^\w*\W/\n/;D' file
```

If the start of the line is a valid string followed by a `{`, replace the `{` by a newline, print/delete the first line in the pattern space and repeat.

Otherwise, reduce the pattern space and repeat until all strings are matched.

N.B. A valid string in this case is a word i.e. alphanumeric or an underscore.